# Xamarin.Android - RSACryptoServiceProvider CspParameters are null and CryptoKeySecurity is null using X509Certificate2

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, x509certificate, signing

can't find why my `RSACryptoServiceProvider` returning `null` values and `null` `CryptoKeySecurity` using `X509Certificate2` and `CspParameters` for provider `"Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider"`.

This code works well on Windows application and signs correctly, but on Xamarin.Android I can't figure out what is wrong. Any help would be nice.

Here is code I'm using:

```
private RSACryptoServiceProvider ComputeKey()
    {
        var certificateCollection = new X509Certificate2Collection();
        certificateCollection.Import(Data, Password, KeyStorageFlags);
        foreach (var certificate in certificateCollection)
        {
            if (!certificate.HasPrivateKey)
            {
                continue;
            }

            var key = certificate.PrivateKey as RSACryptoServiceProvider;
            var exportParameters = key.ExportParameters(includePrivateParameters: true);
            var cspParameters = new CspParameters
            {
                ProviderName = "Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider",
                Flags = UseMachineKeyStore ? CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore : CspProviderFlags.NoFlags
            };
            var result = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParameters);
            result.ImportParameters(exportParameters);
            return result;
        }

        throw new ArgumentException("The provided certificate does not have any private keys.");
    }
```

Here is android result:
[image: android result]

And here is working windows result:

[image: windows result]

Comment: Still need help ... anyone please?